# debug the structurally singular and minimize nonlinearity of Modelica models

Tags: modelica, dymola

I build a Modelica model, but when checking the model ([Here is the model download link](https://github.com/Satinelamp/temp/blob/master/HE.mo)), it shows a local singularity like in the following screenshot.
[image]

so I delete the code showed in the error message.

```
h[3]=(hout+hl)/2
```

but although the model checks fine, there is a strong nonlinearity issue which causes the initialization failure.

[image]
[image]

So I try to delete the following code line:

```
h[1]=(hin+hv)/2
```

and the model not only checks but also there is no initialization issue.

[image]

My questions are:

1. When debugging the model singularity, the error message showed by Dymola might be not the singularity source of the model? Is there a general method to find the source of the singularity problem? Or I have to analyze the equations in the model manually?
2. How to minimize the nonlinearity of the Modelica model and ensure convergence? I found this problem exists in many fields, especially in the thermo-hydraulic models, I found that one way to deal with this problem is the way used in [Thermao Power Library from Modelon](https://www.modelon.com/library/thermal-power-library/) and [ThermoSysPro for EDF](https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/ThermoSysPro.html), these two libraries divide the models or connector into two types: flow and volume. To ensure convergence, it requires to use a staggered grid scheme like in the following screenshot.

   So is there another method to deal with the nonlinearity problem in thermo-hydraulic models? 
   is there a common view on how to deal with the nonlinearity problem in thermo-hydraulic models?

[image]